# Android Studio always has issues when I close a project to open another

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, whenever I open a new project after closing one, I always have .iml issues (Gradle sync failing etc..).

So I either invalidate cache and restart or delete .idea folder or both but I'm not supposed to do that.

What is the correct way to close/open a project ? Version 3.4.2

Comment: what is the full error message?

Comment: have you tried to upgrade to 3.5?